# rmarkdown passing yaml parameter to input tex file

Tags: r, yaml, latex, r-markdown

Please consider the following reproducible example

'index. Rmd'

```
---
title: "mytitle"
author: 'me'
par1: 'something'
par2: 'else'
output: 
    pdf_document:
        template: minimal.tex
---

body stuff here
```

'minimal.tex'

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\input{first.tex}
$title$\\
$author$\\
$body$\\
\input{last.tex}
\end{document}
```

'first.text'

```
\begin{titlepage}
first page cover\\
$par1$\\
\end{titlepage}
```

'last.tex'

```
\begin{titlepage}
last page cover\\
$par2$
\end{titlepage}
```

I need to knit the 'index.Rmd' to a pdf output by passing the yaml parameters, respectively called 'par1' and 'par2', to the content of the two input tex files: 'first.tex' and 'last.tex';

I managed quickly to pass the yaml parameters to the template 'minimal.tex', see for example 'title' and 'author, but I got stuck when passing the content of the other two yaml parameters 'par1' and 'par2' inside the two additional tex files 'first.tex' and 'last.tex', that both are going to be input (imported) into the 'minimal.tex' template (as a result I have got a literal 'par1' and 'par2' instead of the respective variable contents)

sorry, I'm pretty new to latex and Rmd, have you got any solution for this?